# Create image type from module in Prestashop

Tags: image, module, prestashop

I would like to know if there is a way to create a image type from a module installation.
If so, how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a row in ps_image_type table with Db::getInstance()->execute method